# define size of table in xtable

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, xtable

How can I define the size of table in xtable?
I am using this code in knitr to render the table to PDF.
I want my table to be square (length and width same)

```
library(xtable)
df <- data.frame(value1 = c(1,2,3), value2 = c(10,200,3000), value3 = c(100,2000,30000))
print(xtable(df))
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to regulate this is probably with the `align` argument to `xtable()`. Here's an example showing the default behavior and then setting the width of the three right-most columns to 1.5in wide:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<a, results="asis">>=
library(xtable)
df <- data.frame(value1 = c(1,2,3), value2 = c(10,200,3000), value3 = c(100,2000,30000))
print(xtable(df))
@

<<b, results="asis">>=
df <- data.frame(value1 = c(1,2,3), value2 = c(10,200,3000), value3 = c(100,2000,30000))
print(xtable(df, align = c("l", rep("p{1.5in}", 3))))
@

\end{document}
```

Note that the `align` argument is to `xtable`, not `print.xtable`. Here's  the PDF output:

[image]

Comment: How can I find what measurements are legal (like the `1.5in`), and what characters before it work (like the `p`)?